# APK upload error: Permission denied 403 the caller does not have permission

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to upload APK to Firebase using Gradle as mentioned below

```
./gradlew assembleRelease appDistributionUploadRelease -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.xx.xx.xx -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 "-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost" --stacktrace
```

However, it failed with the following error

**Error**

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/xxxxxxxxx/apps/1:xxxxxxxxx:android:0a4f47b9fe3f6250/releases:upload
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385911/firebase-app-distribution-failed-to-fetch-app-information-403-the-caller-do) to resolve the issue but with NO luck

1. Upgraded `Gradle plugin` to use latest version build.gradle
2. Provided following permissions to `client_email` in **ServiceAccount**

- Firebase Admin
- Firebase App Distribution Admin
- Firebase App Distribution Admin SDK Service Agent
- Owner
- Service Account User

I saw similar issues in SO but not sure what am I missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase - App Distribution failed to fetch app information: \[403\] The caller does not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385911/firebase-app-distribution-failed-to-fetch-app-information-403-the-caller-do)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and in my case project id from API call was different from the project id where I have Service Account with the role `Firebase App Distribution Admin`.

So please double check that `xxxxxxx` from this URL `POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/xxxxxxxxx/` is exactly the same where you have SA that is used to access this API.

**NOTE**: to see API calls in logs would be enough to add `--info` option to you `./gradlew` command e.g. `./gradlew --debug <task>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388910/3553843) and I looked up for the email for firebase app distribution in [google developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=) I didn't found it there so I  had to add it with "Firebase App Distribution Admin" Role and that solved my problem